# What does stata's laglimit mean?

Tags: stata, generalized-moments

I just saw an explanation to xtabond2 here

```
xtabond2 depvar varlist [if exp] [in range] [weight] [, level(#)
                svmat twostep robust cluster(varname) noconstant small
                noleveleq orthogonal gmmopt [gmmopt ...] ivopt [ivopt ...]
                pca components(#) artests(#) arlevels h(#) nodiffsargan
                nomata]
```

with the explanation in `gmmstyle()`:

The optional laglimits(a b) suboption can override these defaults: for the transformed equation, lagged levels dated t-a to t-b are used as instruments, while for the levels equation, the first-difference dated t-a+1 is normally used.

I am quite confused about this. Can anyone explain that with a concrete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful heuristic is that complicated (long helpfile) AND popular community-contributed/user-written Stata commands usually have a Stata Journal article that explains things in more detail. Sometimes there are also website or more informal documents instead that you can find using Google.

From the [SJ paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0159) on `xtabond2` contains some good examples:

> The `laglimits()` suboption overrides the defaults on lag range. For
> example, `gmmstyle(w, laglimits(2 .))` specifies lags 2 and longer for
> the transformed equation and lag 1 for the levels equation, which is
> the standard treatment for endogenous variables. In general,
> `laglimits(a b)` requests lags a through b of the levels as
> instruments for the transformed data and lag a−1 of the differences
> for the levels data. a and b can each be missing (“.”). a defaults to
> 1 and b to infinity, so that `laglimits(. .)` is equivalent to leaving
> the suboption out altogether. a and b can even be negative, implying
> forward “lags”. If a>b, `xtabond2` swaps their values. Because the
> `gmmstyle()` varlist allows time-series operators, there are many
> routes to the same specification. For example, if w1 is predetermined
> and w2 endogenous, then instead of `gmmstyle(w1) gmmstyle(w2, laglimits(2 .))`, one `could simply type gmmstyle(w1 L.w2)`.

The Stata manual covers time-series operators (like lags and lag differences) in great detail [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/tstsset.pdf#page=4).

Comment: Thank you so much! But I still have one question. What does gmm(L.(X), lag(2 3)) mean? Does it mean the lag value of t-2 and t-3 for X or?

Comment: `gmm()` is an acceptable abbreviation for `gmmstyle()`, ditto for `lag` and `laglimits()`. L.(X) is $x_{t-1}$, which will be instrumented for with $x_{t-2}$ and $x_{t-3}$

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand that!

Comment: @w12345678 No need to thank me. If this solved your problem, please accept my answer.